# Simple: Remove <li> with classname, then add this classname to next (or current) <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images in a slider like so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dd">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

There is a button to delete the `<li>` with the class "dd", so I have this function going on:

```
function delete(){
    $('li.dd').remove();
}
```

So now that that particulat `<li>` is deleted, I want the class "dd" to be added to either the `<li>` I am currently on. I tried adding this:

```
function delete(){
    $('li.dd').remove();
    $('li').addClass(' dd')
}
```

but as you can see, all it does is add the class to all existing `<li>`s, meaning if I choose to click the delete button again, the entire list is deleted.

I have a pen going on of exactly what I have:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpNwGp

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery methods to make it much cleaner

```js
function toggleSlide(direction) {
  var $visible = $('.slider > li:visible').hide();
  var $ft = $visible[direction ? 'next' : 'prev']();
  if (!$ft.length) {
    $ft = $('.slider > li')[direction ? 'first' : 'last']();
  }
  $ft.show();
  setIndex();
}

function getVisible() {
  return $('.slider > li:visible').index() + 1;
}

function goToEdge(where) {
  $('.slider > li:visible').hide();
  $('.slider > li')[where ? 'last' : 'first']().show();
  setIndex();
}

function addSlide() {
  $('ul.slider').append('<li class="hideable"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x100" alt="Sunset" /></li>');
}

function deleteSlide() {
  var $visible = $('.slider > li:visible');
  toggleSlide(true);
  $visible.remove();
}

function setIndex() {
  $('#slideNumber').text(getVisible())
}

setIndex();
```

```css
.hideable {
  display: none;
}
img {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider" style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:-2em;">
  <li class="hideable dd" style="display: block;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="hinterground" />
  </li>
  <li class="hideable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Berries" />
  </li>
  <li class="hideable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="Cheetah" />
  </li>
  <li class="hideable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100" alt="Fence" />
  </li>
  <li class="hideable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100" alt="Paper" />
  </li>
  <li class="hideable">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x100" alt="Sunset" />
  </li>
  <!-- ... and so on -->
</ul>
<!-- Buttons to go back and forth between slides. -->
<form>
  <input type="button" id="firstButton" value="First" onclick="goToEdge(false)" />
  <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="toggleSlide(false)" />
  <input type="button" value="Forward" onclick="toggleSlide(true)" />
  <input type="button" id="lastButton" value="Last" onclick="goToEdge(true)" />
  <input type="button" value="Add Slide" onclick="addSlide()" />
  <input type="button" value="Delete Slide" onclick="deleteSlide()" />
  <p>Slide
    <!-- you can change "Slide" to Page, Item, etc. --> <span id="slideNumber">
        </span>

  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding class to all the elements, all the `li`s will be removed on next click. You can add the class to only **first** `li` using following methods.

You can use `:first` pseudo-selector to select first element.

```
function delete() {
    $('li.dd').remove();
    $('li:first').addClass('dd');
    //   ^^^^^^
}
```

You can also use `first()` to get first element

```
function delete() {
    $('li.dd').remove();
    $('li').first().addClass('dd');
    //     ^^^^^^^^
}
```

You can check updated codepen [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjBgoe).

Answer (score 0):

save the next element first to add you class:

```
function delete(which) {
    var next_li = $('li.dd').next();
    $('li.dd').remove();
    next_li.addClass("dd");
}
```

i think this might helps you.

good luck.

remember ! do not use `.first()` because it gives the first li `dd` class. not the one that is in line.

Comment: What if the `dd` class is added for the last element

Comment: This still gives the dd class to the next element, not the current.

Comment: current li will removed. so next one will be current dear lulu.

Comment: dear tushar you are right. but easily with one simple 'if' we can check that if the next item is li or not ,if it is, then add 'dd' class to first one. correct ?